# Multi-row Table Constraint in an RDBMS

Tags: java, sql, web-applications, concurrency

Say there is a business level constraint where a given object can have no more than N children objects. If you are creating children objects, how can you ensure that you will never create more than N children objects for that given object?

If you do a READ to get the number of existing children objects, validate that there are less than N, then do an INSERT in the table, there is time between the READ and INSERT where another INSERT could have gotten in.

You don't want to lock the table since this can adversely affect other queries.

A more concrete example is if you have a Resident object and a Home object. In the Resident table, there is something like id, resident_name, home_id. How do you ensure that no more than 4 residents have the same home_id?

Comment: Do that in your program logic and not in SQL

Comment: Well if you do it in the application, then what kind of locking mechanism would you have? I called that out in the second paragraph, where if you do a READ, VALIDATE, then INSERT, another INSERT can get in in-between. Unless you lock the entire table which is bad for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Relational DB constraints aren't designed to implement business rules -- they're designed to protect data integrity at a technical level, and a lot of modern developers don't like them at all, preferring to view the DB as a simple persistence mechanism. Though, having said that, in some databases you can achieve what you want though the use of stored procs and triggers.

If you want to ensure that this rule can 'never' be violated then the DB must become a private data store for a service that is the only method of accessing the database, and all access to it must go via that service. This service could then implement this, and other business rules, in a clear and consistent way.

Comment: I'm totally fine with doing it in application code as well! I am trying to see how you could validate it in application code and still ensure data integrity.

Comment: I don't see how its possible at the DB level without locking the table. Even at an app level you're going to have problems with concurrency.

Comment: One thing I was thinking of would be where any requests to mutate the data on the Resident table would have to get a lock for that specific Home in the home table. Then we can read / validate / mutate data for a Resident on a given Home and be guaranteed no one else is modifying the data from under you. This also prevents adversely affecting other people that are reading / modifying things Residents on another home like what would happen with a full table lock.

Comment: That would lock the whole set of residents for a specific home though. This might be acceptable depending on your application. It's much better than a table lock though. You could maintain a count of residents in the home table too, to avoid having to select count from the residents.